# Sinatra - Test config.ru mapping

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, cucumber

I am new to ruby and sinatra. I have a sinatra application with below mapping in config.ru

```
map "/xyz" do
run lambda { |env|
    if env["PATH_INFO"] != "/"
      A::B.call(env)
    else
      C::D.call(env.merge("PATH_INFO" => "/xyz/"))
    end
  }
end
```

I am trying to write a test to check if the correct app is called.

```
When I visit the URL "<url>" 
And  "<engine>" is used
Examples:
| url       | engine  | 
| /xyz/     | C::D    | 
| /xyz/abc/ | A::B    |
```

And in the step

```
step ":engine is used" do |engine|
  expect(engine.constantise).to receive(:call)
end
```

But the step fails. Is there a better way to test this? I tried debugging this and confirmed that sinatra map and call gets invoked.

The page doesnt exist yet. Thats why I am trying to test the route instead of response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding expection before call to url as below

```
expect(engine.constantize).to receive(:call).and_call_original
get @url
```